# closed graph theorem proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to prove this:

> Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear operator between Banach spaces.
>   Then $T$ is continuous if $T$ is closed.

Here's my take:

> $T$ being closed is equivalent to the graph $\tau = \lbrace (x,T(x)) \rbrace$ is closed. In particular, $\tau$ is a closed subspace of $X \times Y$ with the restriction of the norm $|v \times w| = |v| |w|$.
>
> The projection maps $\pi_y: X \times Y \rightarrow Y$ and $\pi_x: X \times Y \rightarrow X$ are continuous.
>
> Moreover, the restriction $\pi_x | _{\tau}: X \times Y \rightarrow X$
>   is continuous and one-to-one. By the open mapping theorem, $\pi_x | _{\tau}$ is open. It is also surjective since $T$ is defined on on $X$. Hence, this restriction is a homeomorphism.
>
> Finally, $T(x) =   \pi_y  \circ (\pi_x | _{\tau})^{-1} (x)$ is a
>   composition of continuous functions.

I have a hunch there's a gap somewhere in this proof which I can't seem to put a finger on. Could this proof be salvageable if so?

Comment: The norm on $X\times Y$ should be $||(x,y)||:=||x||+||y||$ or $||(x,y)||:=\sqrt{||x||^2+||y||^2}$.

Comment: Aside from changing the norm on $X \times Y$ to $||(x,y)||$ as outlined above, doeas the proof check out?